# Not able to save data using in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a beginner, and started learning MongoDB now. Kindly help me. I am not able to save data from the below code, suggest changes to be made in the code.

I am not able to save the data while entering data through pug. No error is showing. Server is working fine. Database is connected.  The code which I have written in pug is as follows. Kindly see if there is anything else to add or delete in the form.

```
var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    nationality: String
 });
 

var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);
app.post('/person', function(req, res){
    var personInfo = req.body;
    
    if(!personInfo.name || !personInfo.age || !personInfo.nationality){
       res.render('show_message', {
          message: "Sorry, you provided worng info", type: "error"});
    } else {
       var newPerson = new Person({
          name: personInfo.name,
          age: personInfo.age,
          nationality: personInfo.nationality
       });
         
       newPerson.save(function(err, Person){
          if(err)
             res.render('show_message', {message: "Database error", type: "error"});
          else
             res.render('show_message', {
                message: "New person added", type: "success", person: personInfo});
          
       });
    }
 });




html
    head
        title Document
    body
      form(action= "/person", method= "POST")
      div
         label(for= "name") Name: 
         input(name= "name")
      br
      div
         label(for= "age") Age: 
         input(name= "age")
      br
      div
         label(for= "nationality") Nationality: 
         input(name= "nationality")
      br
      button(type= "submit") Create new person
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error is showing and server is working fine.

Comment: Well if you run this code, something should be rendered at the end, right? What is it?

Comment: rendering form, but when I enter and submit data, it is not going anywhere.